# How do you rotate canvas element to mouse position, using vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am working on a mini canvas project and I have been trying to figure out how to rotate the canvas element (rectangle, circle) towards the mouse? I have search it on the web and the examples I see are people using libraries. I know that using a library would be so much easier, but it will take time to learn it. Is there a way to accomplish this using pure native JavaScript?

so far what I have is this:

```
class Player{
 constructor({x, y, radius, round}){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.round = round;
  this.draw(x, y, radius, round);
}
draw(x, y, radius, round){
let that = this;
// begining the path for drawing so that the color doesn't over ride.
c.beginPath();
//this must be on top inorder for color to render.
that.color(player.style.color);
//drawing the rectangle
c.arc(x, y, radius, round, Math.PI * 2);
// creating the outline
c.fill();
// out line to the player
c.linewidth = 10;
// c.strokeStyle = "black";
c.stroke();
c.closePath();
}
 color(color){
  c.fillStyle = color;
  c.strokeStyle = "blue";
 }
}
```

everything works perfectly fine. I am just thinking ahead of how I will make the player rotate to the mouse.

here is the link to the codepen

https://codepen.io/robotosail/pen/abJLQKp

thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: If you mean move the element to mouse position you can check [this](https://codepen.io/vybo-github/pen/jOBGdwZ) I made some changes to your codepen

Comment: my question was on how to rotate the canvas element to the mouse pointer. like how does 2d shooter games do it. But all is well now. your answer was really helpful, because I was able to rewire it and get what I want here is a link to it

https://codepen.io/robotosail/pen/abJLQKp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying to combine your code and mine together here is what I came up with.

```
let canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
canvas[0].setAttribute("id", "canvas");
//initializing the canvas
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");
//the width and height of the canvas
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;

//setting the canvas width and height to be the windows
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

//the player information
let arm_color = "#e8d66f";
let player = {
position :{
x: 509,
y: 300
},
style:{
color: "#e8d66f",
radius: 40,
round: 0,
    stroke_color: "black"
},
};

//the arms
let arm1 = {
position :{
x: 47,
y: 1
},
style:{
color: arm_color,
radius: 15,
round: 0,
    stroke_color: "black"
},
};

let arm2 = {
position :{
x: 1,
y: 47
},
style:{
color: arm_color,
radius: 15,
round: 0,
    stroke_color: "black"
},
};


//drawing the player
class Player{
constructor({x, y, radius, round}){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.radius = radius;
this.round = round;
    
    //calling the draw method
this.draw(x, y, radius, round);
}
draw(x, y, radius, round){
let that = this;
// begining the path for drawing so that the color doesn't over ride.
c.beginPath();
//this must be on top inorder for color to render.
that.color(player.style.color, player.style.stroke_color);
//drawing the rectangle
c.arc(x, y, radius, round, Math.PI * 2);
// creating the outline
c.fill();
// out line to the player
c.linewidth = 10;
// c.strokeStyle = "black";
c.stroke();
c.closePath();
}
color(color, stroke){
c.fillStyle = color;
c.strokeStyle = stroke;
}
}

//drawing the players arms
class Arm{
constructor({x, y, radius, round, color, strokeStyle}){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.radius = radius;
this.round = round;
this.color = color;
    this.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
this.draw(x, y, radius, round, color, strokeStyle);
}
draw(x, y, radius, round, color, strokeStyle){
let self = this;
c.beginPath();
c.fillStyle = color;
c.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
c.arc(x, y, radius, round, Math.PI * 2);
c.fill();
c.stroke();
c.closePath();
}
}

//combining the player's body and arms and make them rotate
class Rotate{
constructor(options){
    this.cx = options.x;
    this.cy = options.y;
    this.radius = options.radius;
    this.color = options.color;
    this.angle  = 0;
    this.toAngle = this.angle;
    
    this.binding();
}
binding(){
    const self = this;
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
        self.update(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    });
}
update(nx, ny){
    this.toAngle = Math.atan2(ny - this.cy, nx - this.cx);
}
render(){
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //saving the current status of the mouse
    c.save();
    //translating to the position of the mouse
    c.translate(player.position.x, player.position.y);
    if(this.toAngle !== this.angle){
        c.rotate(this.toAngle - this.angle);
    }
    
    //the players body
let hero = new Player({x: 0, y: 0, radius: player.style.radius, round: 
player.style.round});
    
    //the players first arm
let heroArm1 = new Arm({x: arm1.position.x, y: arm1.position.y, radius: 
arm1.style.radius, round: arm1.style.round, color: arm1.style.color, strokeStyle: 
arm1.style.stroke_color});
    
    //the players second arm
    let heroArm2 = new Arm({x: arm2.position.x, y: arm2.position.y, radius: 
arm2.style.radius, round: arm2.style.round, color: arm2.style.color, strokeStyle: 
arm2.style.stroke_color});
    c.restore();
 }
}

//combining the players arms and body together
let rotatingCircle = new Rotate({x:500, y:300, radius:player.style.radius, color: 
player.style.color});
```

thank your help.